# Integration Methods with Triangle Geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

I recently came across the so-called "Triangle Geometry" in which the area of an equilateral triangle with side length $1$ is fixed to be $1$. I was intrigued by the concept because of its simplicity and it led me to wonder how "Triangle Geometry" might apply to integration.

It certainly seems possible in 2 dimensions since an array of equilateral triangles tessellates 2D space. However, in practice, I haven't come up with any methods that are nearly as simple as the good ol' Riemann Integral.

Has anyone determined a more elegant way to integrate with "Triangle Geometry" or could point me to a resource that has?

Thank you, stay safe everyone!

Comment: I'd also like to add that whomever knows the specific term for this type of geometry, please let me know so I can refine the title and questions.

Comment: Is this a relabeling of sorts? The area of an equilateral triangle with side $a$ is $a^2\sqrt{3}/4$, so if you want a triangle with unit area, the length has to be $2a/3^{1/4}$...

Comment: *"a collection of tetrahedrons fills 3D space"* ... If you are suggesting that [*regular* tetrahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Regular_tetrahedron) (with equilateral-triangle faces) fill space, then this is incorrect. See, for instance, Wikipedia's ["Tetrahedron packing" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron_packing).

Comment: @gt6989b not so much a relabeling as it is redefining. In a sense, this is a more canonical choice for a single unit of area and I think it may lead to elegant integration techniques.

Comment: @Blue, thank you for the correction, I was foolishly thinking of a mixture of tetrahedron and octahedron. I have removed that from the question for now.